# RenderBeginTag for adding button and redirect page OnClick of button

Tags: asp.net

I have used renderbegintag to create tags dynamically,
and i have created html button tag by this ,but i am not getting how to redirect page by passing querystring of id on the click of that button.

My code is:

```
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "Login-btn");
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, "imgDetails");
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick,"Response.Redirect('ProductDetails.aspx?ProductId='+i)");
writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Button);
writer.Write("Details");
writer.RenderEndTag();//button close
```

Comment: thanks its working,i wrote that function in javascript and called.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are writing out a HTML tag that is client side, the `OnClick` is client side as well - this means any script should be *javascript*.

Javascript does not have `Response.Redirect`, so `document.location.href = 'ProductDetails.aspx?ProductId='+i` may work better.

You may want to rethink how you are outputting this - you can add a server side Html control dynamically instead of writing it out this way.